# Angular HttpClient returns string data instead of parsed JSON

Tags: json, angular, angular-httpclient

I've been in the process of migrating a code base from Angular 4.x to 5.x, and I'm running into a strange issue. I have a service function, that is intended to return a list of objects to the front end, which I then massage into a specific data format. I know I'll need to keep the mapping, but I'm a little miffed that it's returning just plain string data.

The original function is this: (using Http from `@angular/http` just renamed to HttpClient)

```
    public GetVendors(showAll = true, screenArea: number = 0): Observable<Array<SelectModel>> {
        let link = AppSettings.API_COMMON_VENDORS;
        let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
        params.set('showAll', showAll.toString());
        params.set('screenArea', screenArea.toString());

        let requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
        requestOptions.search = params;

        return this.httpClient.get(link, requestOptions).map(response => {
            let result = JSON.parse(response.json());
            let list = new Array<SelectModel>();
            let vendors: Array<any> = result;

            vendors.forEach(vendor => {
                list.push(this.CreateSelectModel(vendor));
            });

            return list;
        });
    }
```

and after ripping out ALL of the Http code, here's the function again using `HttpClient` from `@angular/common/http`

```
    public GetVendors(showAll = true, screenArea: number = 0): Observable<Array<SelectModel>> {
        let link = AppSettings.API_COMMON_VENDORS;
        let params: HttpParams = new HttpParams()
            .set('showAll', showAll.toString())
            .set('screenArea', screenArea.toString());

        return this.httpClient.get<Array<any>>(link, {params}).map(response => {
            let list = new Array<SelectModel>();

            response.forEach(vendor => {
                list.push(this.CreateSelectModel(vendor));
            });

            return list;
        });
    }
```

The issue with this is it kind of defeats the purpose of the new client parsing json for me. The `response` object is a string representing the JSON of the data I requested, but it's still in a string form, and not the type defined in the `get<>()` call.

What am I doing wrong here? shouldn't it be parsed already?

Sample Response Data A'la Network Tools in Chrome Dev Tools:
[image]

Sample Response Body:

[image]

Dev Tools Screenshot with Value of `response`
[image]

The backend (C#) responds with this:

```
      [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult Vendors(bool showAll = false, int screenArea = 0)
        {
            var vendors = _commonBL.GetVendorsSlimForUser(UserModel, UserModel.CustomerId, showAll, screenArea);

            return GetJson(vendors);
        }
```

this is how it worked before the Http => HttpClient migration, and it worked with ONE `JSON.parse()` The data in the return line is simply a standard `List<T>`

Comment: By default it should. Check the browser's debugging tools and navigate to the network calls tab. Find the network call that was made to that end point. Do the http headers include the correct `content-type` header with value json? What about the response, is it an array or maybe an object that contains an array?

Comment: yeah, it's coming back as application/json, but still a string.

Comment: You did not answer the 2nd question from my comment. Please include the verbatim response message body in your question as well as the response http headers. A screen shot of the network information would also be acceptable.

Comment: The response is a simple string only. never does it come back as an array of any kind.

Comment: I think you are stating that the response body is a string and not a json object serialized as a string. Based on that it sounds like you have an issue on the server, not your client. Start there.

Comment: the server is responding with JSON, and I can confirm that it's appropriately returned. However, the HttpClient is not serializing the data from the stringified json. I just don't want to brute force this by using `JSON.parse()`

Comment: ↑ (from above) "Please include the verbatim response message body in your question as well as the response http headers. A screen shot of the network information would also be acceptable."

Comment: That response is not JSON. It is JSON wrapped in a string and escaped. The problem is on the server side.

Comment: it's a C# MVC back end that returns the response with `GetJson()`

Comment: OK, Then it _is_ JSON, but it's a JSON string that contains a JSON string.

Comment: so I'm being forced to use `JSON.parse()` despite it being "unnecessary with @angular/common/http"

Comment: Seeing as your server is returning a string (that contains json content) then yes, you will have to call `JSON.parse` on the response. If all your server code returns json strings you could change the behavior of the angular httpclient and intercept the response and call `JSON.parse` as a part of the response pipeline.

Comment: You are not being forced to use `JSON.parse()`. Your server is returning "double JSON'd" data. If you fix that everything will just work.

Comment: Frankly, it was working as expected prior to the Http => HttpClient migration. WITH ONE `JSON.parse()` call

Comment: BTW what is `GetJson`? That is not a method on `System.Web.Mvc.Controller` and I also can't find an extension method for `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`. Perhaps you can easily fix your server side code but you must include how that is being called in your question.

Comment: But what is `GetJson`? That is not an included call in the mvc library so it is probably a custom implementation in your code. Include the implementation of that method in your question please.

Comment: sorry, it was a secondary function that we wrote, and I didn't understand that. this is now fixed. thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the raw response for your data *should* look like:

```
[{"Id":1234,"Name":"Chris Rutherford"}]
```

But this is what it *actually* looks like:

```
"[{\"Id\":1234,\"Name\":\"Chris Rutherford\"}]"
```

So somewhere in your server code, you have applied JSON encoding twice. Once you correct that, `HttpClient` will do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd quote an answer from [this thread](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20770). Hope it will shed some light on how things work, read it thoroughly it enlightened me tough its not easy to find.

> TypeScript only verifies the object interface at compile time. Any object that the code fetches at runtime cannot be verified by
>   TypeScript.
>
> If this is the case, then things like HttpClient.Get should not
>   return Observable of type T. It should return Observable of type Object because
>   that's what is actually returned. Trying to state that it returns T
>   when it returns Object is misleading.
>
> In the documentation the client's return section says this:
>
> > @return an `Observable` of the body as
> >     type `T`.
>
> In reality, the documentation should say:
>
> > @return an `Observable` of the body which
> >     might be `T`. You do not get T back. If you got T back, it would
> >     actually be T, but it's not.

Comment: I can understand it til the last part.

Comment: @ChrisRutherford edited to be understandable, but read the linked article it will help you in detail